# How to use Expression(Of TDelegate).Update Method

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have built a repository using Lambda expressions to filter my entity collections. As a parameter to the method I'm sending `Expression<Func<Case, bool>> exp`. But inside the method I would like to update that same expression with some global filters. I can see that the expression object itself got an Update method, but I can't figure out how it is implemented (and cannot find anything while searching the net).

```
exp.Update(exp.Body, ???);
```

Could anyone give an example??

EDIT: Definition of the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378255.aspx

EDIT2: This is my code (where I try to use .And):

```
Expression<Func<Case, bool>> newExp = c => c.CaseStatusId != (int)CaseStatus.Finished
var binExp = Expression.And(exp.Body, newExp.Body);
ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Expression<Func<Case, bool>>), "c");
return repository.Where(Expression.Lambda<Expression<Func<Case, bool>>>(binExp, 
    new[] { paramExp }).Compile()).ToArray();
```

It fails with the following ArgumentException: Lambda type parameter must be derived from System.Delegate

Comment: Note: `Expression(Of TDelegate)` is VB syntax. At the top of the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1.update?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_1_Update_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Linq_Expressions_ParameterExpression__) you can switch to C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the `Update` method can help you here. It only creates a new lambda, but does not update the original parameters with the new one, you have to do it manually.
I'd recommend having a visitor that replaces the parameter, then you can `And` the expressions together.

In total you would get something like:

```
    private Case[] getItems(Expression<Func<Case, bool>> exp)
    {
        return repository.Where(AddGlobalFilters(exp).Compile()).ToArray();
    }

    private Expression<Func<Case, bool>> AddGlobalFilters(Expression<Func<Case, bool>> exp)
    {
        // get the global filter
        Expression<Func<Case, bool>> newExp = c => c.CaseStatusId != (int)CaseStatus.Finished;

        // get the visitor
        var visitor = new ParameterUpdateVisitor(newExp.Parameters.First(), exp.Parameters.First());
        // replace the parameter in the expression just created
        newExp = visitor.Visit(newExp) as Expression<Func<Case, bool>>;

        // now you can and together the two expressions
        var binExp = Expression.And(exp.Body, newExp.Body);
        // and return a new lambda, that will do what you want. NOTE that the binExp has reference only to te newExp.Parameters[0] (there is only 1) parameter, and no other
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Case, bool>>(binExp, newExp.Parameters);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// updates the parameter in the expression
    /// </summary>
    class ParameterUpdateVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private ParameterExpression _oldParameter;
        private ParameterExpression _newParameter;

        public ParameterUpdateVisitor(ParameterExpression oldParameter, ParameterExpression newParameter)
        {
            _oldParameter = oldParameter;
            _newParameter = newParameter;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(node, _oldParameter))
                return _newParameter;

            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not "closing" this topic. It was "solved" by changing the business logic...

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.And(exp.Body, newExpression.Body);
```

exapmle:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> f = p => true;
var a = Expression.And(f.Body, f.Body);
ParameterExpression pParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "p"); 
var b = (new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }).Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(a,
        new ParameterExpression[] { pParam }).Compile());
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit/give a more specific example?

The .And() method returns a BinaryExpression object, and I need a Expression<Func<Case, bool>> object

Comment: I get the 'The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean' and 'System.Boolean'.' error, when trying to implement this into my code.

Comment: It was off course And I was supposed to use (was a bit tired yesterday). Se my original post for details on my test of the And method...

Comment: Replace Expression.Lambda<Expression<Func<Case, bool>>> with Expression.Lambda<Func<Case, bool>>

Comment: That gives the exception: "Argument type: 'System.Func<Case, bool>' is not assignable to system type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Case, bool>>'"